# Loading spatialite in Python (mod_spatialite vs. libspatialite.so)

Tags: python, spatialite

I would like to write Python scripts that can load Spatialite across Linux platforms and Spatialite versions. For Spatialite versions lower than 4.2, I can use this:

```
from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sql
con = sql.connect("mydb.sqlite")
con.enable_load_extension(True)
con.execute('SELECT load_extension("libspatialite.so");')
```

For Spatialite versions >= 4.2, I must change the last line to:

```
con.execute('SELECT load_extension("mod_spatialite");')
```

Neither is cross compatible for me. Is there a solution for cross compatibility I am missing? I could invoke `try` and `except` using both `load_extension` commands, but I would prefer a one-line solution. Does one exist?